# "Gaps" in the number line?

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Please consider:

$$A = (-∞, x)\,\,\,; \,\,\,B = (x,∞)$$

How to prove that these intervals are adjacent, that is, that point $x$ does not constitute a distance between these sets?

In other words, if there are three points $i$, $j$, $k$ that immediately follow each other, and $j$ is between $i$ and $k$, how do I prove that in the case that $j$ is missing (i.e. not part of the interval), there isn't a *"gap"* between i and $k$?

Comment: You need to do some serious explaining here before anyone can really understand the question: what does "adjacent intervals" mean? What does "point doesn't constitute distance (??) between two sets" really mean? And more bewildering: what does "immediately follow each other" mean when applied to three real points?

Comment: I hope you don't mind helping me clarify what I mean. Here is what I am trying to say by adjacent intervals: assume that [1] set A is comprised of rationals only, [2] these rationals form a sequence which converges on an irrational 2^(1/2), that is, 2^(1/2) is a supremum that does not belong to set A, [3] set B is also comprised of rationals only and has an irrational infimum, 2^(1/2), which does not belong to set B. [4] Given that sequences in both sets A and B converge on the same point 2^(1/2) (i.e. are as close to 2^(1/2) as they can be without touching it), I call sets A and B "adjacent".